# Unable to parse JSON (xmlhttp)

Tags: javascript, php, json, xmlhttprequest

I've gone through literally all of the other questions on this topic but I can't seem to find a fix for this relatively easy problem:

console.log(xmlhtpp.responseText) results in:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Filosofie","image":"yin-yang.png","background_color":"no"},{"id":"2","name":"Politiek","image":"politics.png","background_color":"no"},{"id":"3","name":"Geschiedenis","image":"history.png","background_color":"no"},{"id":"4","name":"Vocabulaire","image":"vocabulary.png","background_color":"no"},{"id":"5","name":"Wetenschap","image":"science.png","background_color":"no"}]
```

The problem occurs when I try to parse the string to an object like so:

```
JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

Which results in the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

The string originates from a PHP file:

```
$results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM library ORDER BY id", true);   

$categories = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $categories[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($categories);
```

I need to loop trough the object eventually but I can't get past the parsing, any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your JSON seems to be correct, and perfectly parsable; something else is probably the problem. Do you perform this AJAX multiple times? Is it possible that *this* run gives you good results, while you are getting an error on a different run when PHP borks?

Comment: What kind of server is it?

Comment: @Amadan Exactly that is the weird thing, I copied the code almost exactly and only changed a couple variable's names. So weird...

Comment: @webdeb XAMPP, apache most likely

Comment: looks like a wrong content-type, try to change the content-type in you php application `header('Content-Type: text/javascript');``

Comment: Is it possible that your content contained unicode characters but had the wrong `Content-Encoding` header? Is the JSON in your question the _exact_ content which produces the error?

Comment: you could also check the response with an Hex-Editor to see the `real` bytes.. feel free to post the output of the hexeditor here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Content-Type from XAMPP is text/html, so your browser is trying to parse it like this..

Set the content-type yourself..

```
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
echo json_encode(["foo", "bar"]);
```

Comment: It sadly doesn't appear to work. The error is still the same and nothing changes. What a god damn mystery. Might there be anything outside of the code that might be causing it? It seems that the javascript as well as the PHP and JSON are correct..

Comment: @user2081044 Someone already mentioned, that it also could be a wrong character set.. maybe the string looks like valid json, but its not

Comment: I copied the code again and did it all over and now it suddenly seems fine?! Nothing has changed, only the variable names but somehow it worked...! Thanks for the help!